# Kubernetes - RBAC issue with ingress controller

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, kubernetes-ingress, rbac, nginx-ingress

I'm following a tutorial by [Diego Martínez](https://medium.com/@diegomrtnzg/secure-your-kubernetes-services-by-using-https-connections-63fa102a90c2), outlining how to use an ingress controller with SSL on K8s. Everything works fine, with the exception of an RBAC error:

`It seems the cluster it is running with Authorization enabled (like RBAC) and there is no permissions for the ingress controller. Please check the configuration`

Does anyone know how I can grant RBAC permissions to this resource?

I'm running on Google Cloud, and for reference, below is the ingress deployment spec

[image: Ingress Deployment]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are deploying nginx-ingress, perhaps the [nginx-ingress Helm chart](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/nginx-ingress) is a simpler way to do it.

You can follow [the guide](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/) on the nginx-ingress documentation installation on RBAC-enabled clusters.

Specifically addressing your question regarding adding the RBAC permissions, you will need to add something like:

```
---
  apiVersion: v1
  kind: ServiceAccount
  metadata:
    name: nginx-ingress-serviceaccount
    namespace: ingress-nginx
    labels:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
      app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
  
  ---
  apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
  kind: ClusterRole
  metadata:
    name: nginx-ingress-clusterrole
    labels:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
      app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
  rules:
    - apiGroups:
        - ""
      resources:
        - configmaps
        - endpoints
        - nodes
        - pods
        - secrets
      verbs:
        - list
        - watch
    - apiGroups:
        - ""
      resources:
        - nodes
      verbs:
        - get
    - apiGroups:
        - ""
      resources:
        - services
      verbs:
        - get
        - list
        - watch
    - apiGroups:
        - "extensions"
      resources:
        - ingresses
      verbs:
        - get
        - list
        - watch
    - apiGroups:
        - ""
      resources:
        - events
      verbs:
        - create
        - patch
    - apiGroups:
        - "extensions"
      resources:
        - ingresses/status
      verbs:
        - update
  
  ---
  apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
  kind: Role
  metadata:
    name: nginx-ingress-role
    namespace: ingress-nginx
    labels:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
      app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
  rules:
    - apiGroups:
        - ""
      resources:
        - configmaps
        - pods
        - secrets
        - namespaces
      verbs:
        - get
    - apiGroups:
        - ""
      resources:
        - configmaps
      resourceNames:
        # Defaults to "<election-id>-<ingress-class>"
        # Here: "<ingress-controller-leader>-<nginx>"
        # This has to be adapted if you change either parameter
        # when launching the nginx-ingress-controller.
        - "ingress-controller-leader-nginx"
      verbs:
        - get
        - update
    - apiGroups:
        - ""
      resources:
        - configmaps
      verbs:
        - create
    - apiGroups:
        - ""
      resources:
        - endpoints
      verbs:
        - get
  
  ---
  apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
  kind: RoleBinding
  metadata:
    name: nginx-ingress-role-nisa-binding
    namespace: ingress-nginx
    labels:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
      app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
  roleRef:
    apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
    kind: Role
    name: nginx-ingress-role
  subjects:
    - kind: ServiceAccount
      name: nginx-ingress-serviceaccount
      namespace: ingress-nginx
  
  ---
  apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
  kind: ClusterRoleBinding
  metadata:
    name: nginx-ingress-clusterrole-nisa-binding
    labels:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
      app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
  roleRef:
    apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
    kind: ClusterRole
    name: nginx-ingress-clusterrole
  subjects:
    - kind: ServiceAccount
      name: nginx-ingress-serviceaccount
      namespace: ingress-nginx
```